# When will compiler generate indirect jump for x86_64, in C language? Can we tell compilers to disable generating indirect jumps?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, clang, llvm

As I know, the compiler would generate indirect jump for continuous, large switch case code block, virtual function table for C++, and in some tail call situation. Also, indirect calls (not jump) for pointers to functions. Any other situations to use indirect jump?

Additionally, can we tell compiler (clang/llvm preferred) not to generate indirect calls unless necessary?

The question may be weird as I'm doing some research on this.

Comment: Using indirect jump is *never* neccessary. In a pinch, one can replace it with push-ing the target-address and then doing a return. Inefficient, but anyway.

Comment: Any way to replace it with a direct jump or something that could be determined before running?

Answer (score -1):

Indirect jumps or calls normally involve an array of pointers (address). In addition to switch case sequences, Microsoft compilers generate an array of pointers to functions when building in debug mode (I'm pretty sure this isn't done in release mode). I don't know how to disable it. There's also an indirect call used to switch context (or just change privilege level), but that shouldn't be an issue for normal C / C++ code.

Comment: "Used to switch context", that means far jump to other code segment, right?

Comment: @WindChaser - switching context is accomplish via call to switch tasks. Scroll down to the part about doing a task switch, link: [call task switch](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html). There's also a gate call used to change privilege level link: [wiki call gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_gate)

Comment: @rcgldr: You know that call gates, tasks and all the rest are avoided for decades now?

Comment: @Deduplicator - True, but that stuff is still part of the X86 instruction set.